# How to call an Object's method that is defined in a different function? [Android]

Tags: java, android, object, countdowntimer

I have this function called startTimer and I created an instance of the CountDownTimer class:

```
public void startTimer(View view){

    CountDownTimer myTime = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {

    }

}
```

The CountDownTimer has a method called cancel() that I want to invoke from a different method, resetTimer():

```
public void resetTimer() {

}
```

Both functions are contained within a single class. How do I call the cancel() method of CountDownTimer from the resetTimer()?

Comment: Why don't you set `myTime` as `private CountDownTimer myTime` in your `single class`?

Comment: Upvote? Really? Please read about class member variables.

Comment: It didn't go through my mind since I am still pretty new to Java. I will give it a try and get back to you asap

Comment: @prijupaul I know only the introductory stuff about Java. StackOverflow has helped me with other languages in various times so hopefully the community will be supportive to help a newbie out.

Comment: @Mobu Before you start coding in OOO languages (Java, C++, Obj-C etc), read the theory part of it and then get into programming. It sure will save much time and lead to better programs. Goodluck!

Comment: @prijupaul I will do that. Currently, I have started reading "Head First OOP Analysis and Design"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private CountDownTimer myTime;

public void startTimer(View view){

    myTime = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {

    }
}

public void reset() {
    myTime.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `myTime` a private global variable (global here meaning "outside of any function"):

```
public class myClass {
    private CountDownTimer myTime = ...

    public void startTimer(View view) {
        myTime.start();
    }

    public void resetTimer() {
        myTime. //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error "Can not Instantiate the type CountDownTimer". Is it because of the constructor?

Comment: Haha the other answer had it. The constructor should go either in the startTimer() function or your class constructor.